# Sql - goto statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, goto

Is it good practice to use 'goto' statements in SQL queries?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: There is no `GOTO` in SQL - only T-SQL

Comment: t-sql is sql, and all sql questions of any flavor should include the sql tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on the SQL - some of the dialects don't provide a useful mechanism for flow control other than GOTO.

GOTO is generally bad form.

Answer (score 9):

Not in production code but for testing could be ok.

For example, wanting to provide regression testing for a stored procedure where the "common bit" is the call to the procedure being tested and debug statements.

```
declare @test int;
set @test = 1;
goto tests

common:
print 'common bit'

tests:
if @test = 1 print '1';
if @test = 2 print '2';
if @test = 3 print '3';

set @test = @test + 1;
if @test <= 3 goto common
print 'finished ' + cast(@test as varchar(5))
go  -- goto can not be used past go!
```

Being a t-sql noob I was hoping for procedure or function to declare within scope to do the "common bit" but this was the best I could come up with after much googling.  Why would you have to setup a stored procedure for every bit of code you want to re-use.  Especially for non production work.

Comment: You make a great point about using small bits of functionality using GOTO. :-)  We need Lambda expressions in T-SQL! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No.

As with other languages, there's almost always a better option to use than a Goto.

If you tell us which SQL Package you're using and what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to give you an idea as to exactly which might fit.

Comment: It's a stored procedure written by someone.

Comment: @BhejaFry - But is it T-SQL, PL-SQL, MySQL, etc.?

Comment: it's T-SQL, won't pl-sql support goto?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be no. My general rule with goto statements in any modern language is, if your using them, something is wrong with your design.

Answer (score 0):

**goto** is keyword with its own feature.
We can use goto whenever it is required to jump directly to some level.

Lets take the example...
In my stored procedure I need to work with data taking in 4 temp tables.
at every level after inserting records in temp table I need to check whether records are present in this temp temp or not, if no records got inserted so instead of processing further I can directly jump down using goto.
label is the point where we should jump:

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmpMsNos (custPo CHAR(24))

    CREATE TABLE #tmpValidBilltos (billto CHAR(12))

    CREATE TABLE #tmpOrders (
        fh_pkey INT
        ,fh_id CHAR(8)
        ,custPo CHAR(24)
        ,lastchOfCustInsert DATETIME
        )

    CREATE TABLE #tmpOrdersFiltered (
        fh_pkey INT
        ,fh_id CHAR(8)
        ,custPo CHAR(24)
        ,lastchOfCustInsert DATETIME
        ,onbDate DATETIME
        ,rapDate DATETIME
        )

    CREATE TABLE #tmpLoad (
        custPo CHAR(24)
        ,ld_pkey INT
        ,ld_wkpmpn CHAR(25)
        ,lda_barcode VARCHAR(30)
        ,ld_createdOn DATETIME
        ,ReceivedDate DATETIME
        ,DispatchedDate DATETIME
        )

INSERT INTO #tmpMsNos
    SELECT cast(itemValue AS CHAR(24)) 
    FROM dbo.fn_array_to_table(@pMsNos, ',')

IF (
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpMsNos
                )
            )
    BEGIN
        GOTO label
    END
INSERT INTO #tmpValidBilltos
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(12), xm_doref)
    FROM xmlref x
    WHERE xm_element = 'THD-BoxtruckRequest'
        AND xm_attribute = 'THD-BoxtruckBillto'

IF (
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpValidBilltos
                )
            )
    BEGIN
        GOTO label
    END

INSERT INTO #tmpOrders
    SELECT fh.fh_pkey
        ,fh.fh_id
        ,fh.fh_custPo
        ,max(coc.ch_dt)
    FROM #tmpMsNos msNos
    INNER JOIN fcfgthd fh ON msNos.custPo = fh.fh_custPo
    INNER JOIN #tmpValidBilltos bt ON bt.billto = fh.fh_bt_id
    LEFT JOIN chofcust coc ON coc.ch_fhpkey = fh.fh_pkey
    WHERE fh.fh_statcode NOT IN (
            98 --CAN
            ,99 --DEL
            )
        AND fh.fh_ship_dt > @startDate
    GROUP BY fh.fh_pkey
        ,fh.fh_id
        ,fh.fh_custPo

    IF (
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpOrders
                )
            )
    BEGIN
        GOTO label
    END

INSERT INTO #tmpOrdersFiltered
    SELECT t.fh_pkey
        ,t.fh_id
        ,t.custPo
        ,t.lastchOfCustInsert
        ,MAX(cocONB.ch_dt)
        ,MAX(cocRAP.ch_dt)
    FROM (
        SELECT tmpO.fh_pkey
            ,tmpo.fh_id
            ,tmpO.custPo
            ,tmpO.lastchOfCustInsert
        FROM #tmpOrders tmpO
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT custpo
                ,max(lastchOfCustInsert) AS MaxInserteddate
            FROM #tmpOrders
            GROUP BY custpo
            ) tmpOgrouped ON tmpO.custpo = tmpOgrouped.custpo
            AND tmpO.lastchOfCustInsert = tmpOgrouped.MaxInserteddate
        ) AS t
    LEFT JOIN chofcust cocRAP ON cocRAP.ch_fhpkey = t.fh_pkey
        AND cocRAP.ch_stat = 2 -- RAP --TODO: Add comment with status code like 98, 99 -- CAN, DEL for readability - Paresh
    LEFT JOIN chofcust cocONB ON cocONB.ch_fhpkey = t.fh_pkey
        AND cocONB.ch_stat = 5 -- ONB --TODO: Add comment with status code like 98, 99 -- CAN, DEL for readability - Paresh
    GROUP BY t.fh_pkey
        ,t.fh_id
        ,t.custPo
        ,t.lastchOfCustInsert

    --TODO: Take an exit if no order found into #tmpOrdersFiltered table, while taking a early exit make sure it doesn't break the calling code (C#)  - Paresh
    IF (
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpOrdersFiltered
                )
            )
    BEGIN
        GOTO label
    END
INSERT INTO #tmpLoad
    SELECT o.custPo
        ,l.ld_pkey
        ,l.ld_wkpmpn
        ,la.lda_barcode
        ,max(coc.ch_dt)
        ,CASE ISNULL(w.xl_date, '')
            WHEN ''
                THEN o.rapDate
            ELSE w.xl_date
            END AS ReceivedDate
        ,CASE ISNULL(mm.me_ecpkey, '')
            WHEN ''
                THEN o.ONBDate
            ELSE NULL
            END AS DispatchedDate
    FROM #tmpOrdersFiltered o
    INNER JOIN fcload l ON l.ld_fhpkey = o.fh_pkey
    LEFT JOIN loadanc la ON la.lda_ldpkey = l.ld_pkey
    LEFT JOIN wkxaclog w ON w.xl_ldpkey = l.ld_pkey
    LEFT JOIN multiexceps mm ON mm.me_ldpkey = l.ld_pkey
        AND mm.me_ecpkey = @missingitemexcep
    LEFT JOIN chofcust COC ON coc.ch_ldpkey = l.ld_pkey
        AND coc.ch_stat = 64 -- 64= ILH
    GROUP BY o.custPo
        ,l.ld_pkey
        ,l.ld_wkpmpn
        ,la.lda_barcode
        ,w.xl_date
        ,o.rapDate
        ,mm.me_ecpkey
        ,o.ONBDate
```