# Skip or Run Line of Code Determined by Variable T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Currently I have a query full of commented blocks of code that I activate/deactivate manually. My plan is to put everything in one stored procedure and have parameters to determine which commented blocks of code should run. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a GOTO  (depreciated)  Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I may be wrong about the depreciated status.

Comment: I previously saw the docs, and then saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046017/sql-goto-statement

So I was wondering if there were other ways to go about this, but I guess I'll give it a go. My code is already poorly designed.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to re-tool and improve  ... the value-add is the fun part  :)

Comment: Monday motivation! Cheers.

Comment: You "have **a** query full of commented blocks of code", not multiple statements? It sounds like you are trying to enable/disable joins and filtering conditions. If you would show us a bit'o'code it would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` is vastly preferable to `GOTO`.  And you can generally avoid jumping around in the procedure or having lots of nested `IF` blocks with a pattern like this;

```
IF ...
BEGIN
  --DO SOMETHING
  RETURN;
END

IF ...
BEGIN
  --DO SOMETHING ELSE
  RETURN;
END
```

And it's the first step to refactoring the code blocks into separate single-responsibility stored procedures.